# find where is stored a setting value

Tags: operating-system

I want to find all files containing a particular setting value, let's say "string".
Is it safe to simply looking for "string" with the command "grep -r string"?
Or is it possible that "string" can be someway hidden under a different format that grep cannot discover (encryption excluded)?

Comment: Grep simply looks at the text on each line. So providing it's not obfuscated grep should work.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` will not help you find `string` in an encrypted file.  It simply looks for the pattern in files.

Comment: and which tool I can use to find strings in ANY file on Windows?

Comment: I do not know of any.  Encryption will change the strings in different ways, even if you are using the same encryption algorithm, depending on the frequency of occurrence of patterns and the other patterns around it.  Your best bet will be to decrypt the file before looking for the patterns.

Comment: I'm only interested on plain text files anyway

Comment: Then you do not have an issue.